# Allow a drop-down element to overflow a container that has hidden or scrolled overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I have horizontally scrollable container and opened dropdown inside (position: absolute). I want the opened dropdown to overflow vertically this container. `overflow-y: visible` doesn't work and container is scrollable vertically anyway.

Here is simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/matcygan/4rbvewn8/7/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="dd-toggle">Dropdown toggle
            <div class="dd-list">Opened drop down list</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
.container >div {
    width: 300px;
}
.dd-toggle {
    position: relative;
    background: grey;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.dd-list {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    background: #ff9c00;
    width: 70px;
}
```

[image: image explanation what I want to achieve]

Comment: Sidenote: what about stop using tables for layout? You should use them only for data representation...

Comment: Thanks for sidenote, but this is only simplified version of layout as you can see. Table is complex and used to present comparable data and dropdown is part of multiple-select.

Comment: Table has nothing to problem anyway... Question edited

Comment: You can set "height for "container" element

Answer (score 4):

It can be done, but requires three levels of control:

- The outer container exists to establish the relative positioning.
- Its content container controls the size and overflow.
- The drop-down container reacts to the cursor.

For this:

[image: screenshot]

Try this:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Popout Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style>
            .container {
                position: relative;
            }       
            .content {
                width: 10em;
                max-height: 5em;
                overflow: scroll;
            }       
            .dropdown {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #CCC;
                overflow: visible;
                display: none;
            }       
            :hover>.dropdown {
                display: block;
            }       
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <h1>Popout Test</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="content">
            <li>Alpha</li>
            <li>Bravo</li>
            <li>Charlie &gt;
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li>One</li>    
                    <li>Two</li>    
                    <li>Three</li>  
                    <li>Four</li>   
                    <li>Five</li>   
                    <li>Six</li>    
                </ul>       
            </li>   
            <li>Delta</li>
            <li>Echo</li>
            <li>Foxtrot</li>
            <li>Golf</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What if you want the dropdown to be a fluid 100% width of its parent container, say `.dropdown-wrapper`? I don't see any way of doing that other than making the wrapper `position: relative`, which results in the original problem again of the dropdown not being visible beyond the container.

Comment: This solution sucks. It makes the dropdown options element positioned correctly only when we don't scroll down. Scroll down a bit and then hover - it's not even clear that these options belong to the "Charlie" element then.

Comment: Thank you, it works well as in your example, but CSS is unfortunately full of gotchas. When you have absolute element inside table (which in turn is inside some scrollable element) this trick does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I fixed mine with javascript since the CSS solution does not move the dropdown options when the parent has been scrolled horizontally.

Here is how I did it using JavaScript:

```
<style>
.outer-container {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
  gap: 20px; 
  width: 200px; 
  background-color: gainsboro;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.content {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.content::after {
  content '&darr'
  display: block;
}

.content ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>

<div class='outer-container'>
  <div class='container' id='scrollable'>
    <span>Home</span>
    <span>About</span>
    <span class='content' id='content'>
      Dropdown
      <ul id='dropdown'>
        <li>option1</li>
        <li>option2</li>
        <li>option3</li>
        <li>option4</li>
      </ul>
    </span>
    <span>Contact</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
const scrollable = document.getElementById("scrollable")
const content = document.getElementById("content")
const dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown")

scrollable.addEventListener(
  'scroll',
  () => {
    const contentRect = content.getBoundingClientRect()
    dropdown.style.left = contentRect.left + 'px'
  }
)
</script>
```

You can check it out on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tammibriggs/pen/gOKyWgG)

Answer (score -1):

Add `position: static` to the parent element.

Comment: worked to mee also!