# overflow-x: scroll and overflow-y:visible nightmare with x-scrolling and dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Before i start, I wanted to let you know that I have been searching high and low for a solution to my issue but the closest thread I've found is unfortunately without the answer to the actual problem - [Position absolute inside div with overflow-x scroll and overflow-y visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616525/position-absolute-inside-div-with-overflow-x-scroll-and-overflow-y-visible)

Essentially I got main page where I am dynamically loading some other pages and on some of them I used dropdown listboxes. It happened that I haven't noticed it earlier as content any of the pages wasn't wide enough for me to spot the problem.

The problem I face is absolutely positioned div (which contain dropdown) and visible horizontal scroll bar on the parent of this div. When I scroll my page horizontally the dropdown div stays in the same place on the screen. 
I read about "popping out" absolute divs under this link:
https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ but even there, I can observe similar issue I am currently facing, which is appearing of the vertical scroll on the parent element.
 I am trying to achieve similar effect like here:
 
http://jsfiddle.net/matcygan/4rbvewn8/7/ but stop vertical scroll bar to appear when the listbox is expanded - instead it should overflow the box and party cover horizontal scroll bar.
 Here I've found another prompt example how can I achieve it http://jsfiddle.net/b5fYH/ but when i try to play with it and make red boxes scrollable with content as well as overflowing outside of the content vertically, without creating vertical scrollbar, I am failing... 
 I am also fine with using JS if CSS on it's own can't deliver such effect.
In the end after 3 days battle, the CSS won and I need to ask for a help...

Any support will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.