# Table Overflow Auto with Absolute Positions

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive table to enable horizontal scrolling on smaller screens using `overflow-x: auto` (the `table-responsive` class from bootstrap takes care of that). At the end of each table row, I have a main button that opens up a dropdown with other buttons. The expected functionality is that upon clicking on the main button, the dropdown opens without changing anything else. For that I am using positions `relative` and `absolute`.

However, on the last row, when clicking on the button, because of the `overflow-x:auto` property, it's enabling vertical scroll. If I remove the `overflow` property, everything works as intended except for the table horizontal scroll. Here is a fiddle to show the problem https://jsfiddle.net/06ck31m5/

```js
function openDropdown(idx) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('dropdown' + idx);
    elem.classList.toggle('show');
}

let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-btn');
for(let i = 0; i<btns.length;i++) {
 btns[i].onclick = () => {
     openDropdown(btns[i].dataset.id);
    };
}
```

```css
#dropdown1,
#dropdown2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.table-responsive {
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: gray;
}

.table {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.button-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.show {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Random 1</th>
                    <th>Random 2</th>
                    <th>Random 3</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>John Smith</td>
                    <td>USA</td>
                    <td>Just Filler</td>
                    <td>Ignore This</td>
                    <td>Random</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="button-wrapper">
                            <button class="dropdown-btn" type="button" data-id="1">Open</button>
                            <div id="dropdown1">
                                <button>Button1</button>
                                <button>Button2</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Victor</td>
                    <td>Venezuela</td>
                    <td>Just Filler</td>
                    <td>Ignore This</td>
                    <td>Random</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="button-wrapper">
                            <button class="dropdown-btn" type="button" data-id="2">Open</button>
                            <div id="dropdown2">
                                <button>Button1</button>
                                <button>Button2</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A not-so-clever solution would be to add a padding-bottom for the "table-container". What do you think about it? (At least 25px..)

Comment: @Hunor I changed to fiddle to include a background color on the table container since that better reflects my situation. By adding a padding, it will increase the size of the container unecessarily which I don't want

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to make the dropdown extend beyond the overflow limit, I answered [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616525/allow-a-drop-down-element-to-overflow-a-container-that-has-hidden-or-scrolled-ov/56264438#56264438) yesterday.

Basically, it needs three levels:

- An outer container to establish the relative positioning.
- A content container to control the size and overflow.
- A drop-down container to react to the cursor, positioned relative to the outer container, not the content container.

Comment: The problem with this is, when the table becomes scrollable, the dropdown accompanies the scroll instead of staying fixed in place under the main button

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to add a padding-bottom for the "table-container" - Easy and quick if, and only if, the bottom-padding is not disturbing anything.

```js
function openDropdown(idx) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('dropdown' + idx);
    elem.classList.toggle('show');
}

let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-btn');
for(let i = 0; i<btns.length;i++) {
 btns[i].onclick = () => {
     openDropdown(btns[i].dataset.id);
    };
}
```

```css
#dropdown1,
#dropdown2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.table-responsive {
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: gray;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.table {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.button-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.show {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Random 1</th>
                    <th>Random 2</th>
                    <th>Random 3</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>John Smith</td>
                    <td>USA</td>
                    <td>Just Filler</td>
                    <td>Ignore This</td>
                    <td>Random</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="button-wrapper">
                            <button class="dropdown-btn" type="button" data-id="1">Open</button>
                            <div id="dropdown1">
                                <button>Button1</button>
                                <button>Button2</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Victor</td>
                    <td>Venezuela</td>
                    <td>Just Filler</td>
                    <td>Ignore This</td>
                    <td>Random</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="button-wrapper">
                            <button class="dropdown-btn" type="button" data-id="2">Open</button>
                            <div id="dropdown2">
                                <button>Button1</button>
                                <button>Button2</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```